# How can I multithreadedly download a HuggingFace dataset?

Tags: python, multithreading, download, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I want to download a HuggingFace dataset, e.g. [`uonlp/CulturaX`](https://huggingface.co/datasets/uonlp/CulturaX):

```
from datasets import load_dataset
ds = load_dataset("uonlp/CulturaX", "en")
```

However, it downloads on one thread at 50 MB/s, while my network is 10 Gbps. Since this dataset is 16 TB, I'd prefer to download it faster so that I don't have to wait for a few days. How can I multithreadedly download a HuggingFace dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use the [`num_proc`](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/loading#multiprocessing) attribute (thanks [Quentin Lhoest](https://huggingface.co/lhoestq) for [pointing me](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-can-i-multithreadedly-download-a-huggingface-dataset/56178) to it):

```
from datasets import load_dataset
ds = load_dataset("uonlp/CulturaX", "en", num_proc=8)
```

Note that [`uonlp/CulturaX`](https://huggingface.co/datasets/uonlp/CulturaX) has been gated since the question was posted. One must therefore first run in a terminal:

```
huggingface-cli login --token $HUGGINGFACE_TOKEN
```

where `$HUGGINGFACE_TOKEN` can be found on https://huggingface.co/settings/tokens

and go to [`uonlp/CulturaX`](https://huggingface.co/datasets/uonlp/CulturaX) to accept the dataset access agreement.